# At what speed do kids normally teeth?

Tags: infant, teething

This is a follow-up question to my other question [here](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/are-calcium-supplements-helpful-for-a-teething-infant)

My son finally started teething and his first bud appeared around a week after the question was posted :)

But now the teething has again stopped at that first bud. Its been almost a month and I don't see any more whites. The gums are still hard and he still chews on anything he can lay his hands on. I thought the lower incisors always came in together.

Not sure if this is normal or a cause for me to worry... Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can tell you this.  It can vary from child to child, but if you are concerned, I would recommend talking to your pediatrician.  Teething can last for a while though, my son was still teething up until 20 months.  I still think he slightly teething.  Also, you may not think your son has any more whites, but it may not be very noticeable, so keep that in mind as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, it's normal.**

Congrats on the first tooth! :-)

Teeth rarely come out in matching pairs, or at regular intervals, or starting with the front ones and then the next and the next.

It might take weeks while nothing happens, then one or several will come out in short succession, then possibly a long period of nothing again. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

My son has been going through the same thing. No teeth through the gums yet despite being in teething mode for a month and a half. I've read that it can take up to 3 months for teeth to get through.

Comment: yup, the first one was out after 2 long months! I can feel the other teeth beneath the gums, his gums are very hard these days... But the things just won't come out!!!

Comment: @lostInTransit -  It will eventually happen.

Answer (score 1):

Unless he could have a severe calcium or vitamin deficiency (quite unlikely in industrialized countries, and you'd likely notice other effects), I wouldn't worry about it.  Tooth eruption is highly variable.  For instance, my son got his first eight teeth within one month of each other; on average it takes five.

Comment: He's a hyperactive kid. So I doubt there's any deficiency of any kind :)